# Create Model from unrelated View on Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller

I'm trying to do something fairly simple but I'm not sure the rails way to do it.  At its simplest, I have an index page where you can sign up for a mailing list.

I'm trying to set it up so that you can add yourself to the mailing list from the index page without ever seeing the mailing list views.  I can submit the data properly using something like:

```
= form_for @mailing_list, :remote => true do |form| 
= if @mailing_list.errors.any?
  %ul
  = @mailing_list.errors.full_messages.each do |message| 
    %li
      = message
.field
  = form.label :email, 'Your email'
  = form.text_field :email
= form.submit "Add to Mailing List"
```

With the controller:

```
def create
  @mailing_list = MailingList.new(params[:mailing_list])
  if @mailing_list.save
    redirect_to(:root, :notice => 'Mailing list was successfully created.') 
  else
    ? How do I return the errors ?
  end
end
```

But I am unable to get the errors back (ie. Email not valid, etc.).  Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting?  I would just like to be able to call and respond to actions of the MailingList controller from the index page view...

Comment: Are you wanting :remote => true?

Comment: not really, thats just my inexperience with ruby.  i was hoping to do it all without ajax.  Should I be posting to the index page controller and creating a mailing list entry from there instead of posting to the the mailing list controller?

Comment: I think that you are fine. Just remove the :remote => true if you don't want to use AJAX.  However, I like the ability to not have to move the user from the page.  It is a pain to try to redirect the user back.  Try the code below and let me know what you think.

Comment: @natedavidsolds thanks for your help, your code is what I had before, but it moves me to /mailing_list instead of keeping me on / when there is an error (when successful, everything is great)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are wanting a form that will add someone to a Mailing list without leaving that page.

Better? Hmmm..  Well, I'll tell you what I do and you can decide what you like.

I would use `respond_to` in the controller to differentiate between the standard html call and the remote js call.  Then, I would handle the page changes in the view. I like keeping the display in the views.

Controller:

```
def create
    @mailing_list = MailingList.new(params[:mailing_list])
    if @mailing_list.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to(:root, :notice => 'Mailing list was successfully created.') }
            format.js { render }    
        end 
    else
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render }
            format.js { render :errors }
        end
    end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
$('#errors').html('').hide();
$('form').html('Mailing list was successfully created.'); // needs a better element
```

errors.js.erb

```
$('#errors').html('<%= escape_javascript(@mailing_list.errors.full_messages.collect { |msg| content_tag :li, msg }.join().html_safe) %>').show();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something with the errors object on @mailing_list, e.g.

```
flash.now[:error] = @mailing_list.errors.full_messages
```